# Allow Profile the ability to edit any Task or Event on Account or Contact

Tags: profile, sharing, tasks, sharing-rule, activityhistory

I have a dilly of a pickle here.
We have users who have the profile: "US-Development".
Anyone with this profile should be able to edit any Task or Event on Account or Contact.

One of our staff members came to me and said that they are not able to edit a Task (specifically "Log-a-call") on an Account record.  They get an insufficient privileges error).
The tasks that they can't edit are the ones that are assigned to other staff members.
I'm an Administrator so I went in and for the ones they can't edit I changed the Task's "Assigned To" field to be the person who got insufficient privileges error and they can now edit just the ones that I changed the "Assigned To" field, but I need them to be able to edit ANY Task or event on Contact or Account.

I was reading that the profile just needs "Modify All", and I went to the "US-Development" profile Object settings and verified that their profile has "Modify All" set for Accounts.

[image]

I went to Sharing Settings and saw that Account is set up like this:

[image]

and I went to the bottom of the Sharing Settings page and saw there is nothing set for Account, which is what I would expect to override Profile object settings:
[image]

How do I give my US-Development profile access to edit other peoples Tasks, Events (that show up under Activity History) for Contact and Account?

Comment: Take a look at https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/data_security/data_security_records and https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385354&type=1

Answer (score 0):

The OWD for Activities is probably set to "Private".  Change it to "Controlled by Parent" and that should fix it.